# xslt преобразование (html table) для объединения ячеек (rowspan)

Tags: html, xslt, table

Дано: html - таблица, точнее фрагмент .....
      В первом столбце нужно объединять ячейки (подряд идущие с объединением текста) на основании содержимого первой ячейки, содержащей наименование дня недели. Пример:

```
<table>
<tr> <td> 1 июня. Понедельник. Комментарий 1 </td> <td>08:00</td>
<td>Зарядка</td></tr>
<tr> <td> Комментарий 2 </td> <td>09:00</td><td>Завтрак</td></tr>
<tr> <td> Комментарий 3 </td> <td>10:00</td><td>Кружок "Умелые руки"</td>
</tr>
<tr> <td> 2 июня. Вторник. Комментарий 4 </td> <td>08:00</td>
<td>Зарядка</td>
...
</table>
```

После преобразования должно быть следующее:

```
<table>
    <tr> <td rowspan="3"> 1 июня. Понедельник. Комментарий 1 <br/> 
Комментарий 2 <br/>
Комментарий 3 </td> 
<td>08:00</td><td>Зарядка</td></tr>
<tr>  <td>09:00</td><td>Завтрак</td></tr>
<tr>  <td>10:00</td><td>Кружок "Умелые руки"</td></tr>
<tr> <td> 2 июня. Вторник. Комментарий 4 </td> <td>08:00</td>
<td>Зарядка</td>
...
```

Возможно ли вообще не очень сложным инструкциями  xsl/xpath составить такое преобразование или придётся писать спец. утилиту на одном из ЯП?

Answer (score 0):

Я посмотрел, оказалось, что проще сделать утилиту (метод), который преобразовывает указанную таблицу (написан на С#)

```
    static Regex weekdays = new Regex("(Понедельник|Вторник|Среда|Четверг|Пятница|Суббота|Воскресенье)", RegexOptions.Compiled|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    /// <summary>
    /// Объединяет ячейки, у которых первый элемент 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableElement">Table element.</param>
    public static void MergeCells(XmlElement tableElement){
        var rows = tableElement.SelectNodes (".//tr").Cast<XmlElement> ().ToArray ();
        XmlElement curr_first = null;
        var count = 0;
        foreach(XmlElement row in rows){
            var td = row.SelectSingleNode ("./td[1]");
            if (!weekdays.IsMatch (td.InnerText)) {
                count++;
                //Скопируем содержимое в базовый.
                if (curr_first != null) {
                    var br = tableElement.OwnerDocument.CreateElement ("br");
                    curr_first.AppendChild (br);
                    foreach (XmlNode child in td.ChildNodes)
                        curr_first.AppendChild (child.CloneNode(true));
                //Теперь удаляем сам элемент и увеличиваем счётчик rowspan
                curr_first.SetAttribute ("rowspan", count.ToString());
                }
                td.ParentNode.RemoveChild (td);
            } else {
                curr_first = td as XmlElement;
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```